# Remove "Open in new window" option from Windows Explorer right-click menu

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, context-menu

Is there a way to remove the "Open in new window" right-click menu option on directories in Windows Explorer on Windows 7?

[image: Open in new window]

Comment: Any particular reason why you need to remove this option?

Comment: I never use it, but will hit it by accident occasionally, so I would prefer to remove the cause of my annoyance altogether. (If I wanted to open it in a new window, I would have used `Ctrl+Click` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this forum for more information:

http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/5127-remove-include-library-context-menu.html

Create the appropriate REG file(s) using this code and then run them:

**ADD 'Open in a New Window' Option**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\opennewwindow]
"MUIVerb"="@shell32.dll,-8517"
"MultiSelectModel"="Document"
"OnlyInBrowserWindow"=""
"LaunchExplorerFlags"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\opennewwindow\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}"
```

**REMOVE 'Open in a New Window' Option**

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\opennewwindow]
"MUIVerb"="@shell32.dll,-8517"
"MultiSelectModel"="Document"
"OnlyInBrowserWindow"=""
"LaunchExplorerFlags"=dword:00000001

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\opennewwindow\command]
"DelegateExecute"="{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}"
```

Comment: Removing the key entirely appears to cause problems with using `Win+E` to open a new explorer window (and maybe other situations as well). Since I only really need to remove the accelerator key to avoid accidentally activating the menu item from the keyboard, changing the `MUIVerb` value to a hard coded string instead of a resource identifier worked well enough. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Values like LaunchExplorerFlags are undocumented and I don't recommend that you delete/write such values on random systems. Especially when there is a non-destructive way to hide menu commands.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide a static verb (menu command defined in the registry) by making it a [extended verb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127433(v=vs.85).aspx). Extended verbs are only visible when you hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> when opening the menu.

The best part is, you don't even have to be an administrator to do this:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Folder\shell\opennewwindow]
"Extended"=""
```

Change `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` to apply it to all users on the machine.